# How can I change a variable name each time in a for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have created a python program that works fine. but I want to make it more neat, I ask the user for numbers, number1, number2 etc. up to 5. I want to just do this with a for loop though, like this

```
for i in range(0,5):
    number(i) = int(input("what is the number"))
```

I realise that this code docent actually work but that is kind of what I want to do.

Comment: Try a dictionary, use the keys for the variable names, and the values for the values.

Comment: You can also use a list. i.e. `numbers = []`,  and `number.append(int(input("what is the number")))` — which might be more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
number = []
for i in range(5):
    number.append(int(input("what is the number ")))
print(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest I could think at the top of my had way would just to create a list and append the items:

```
numbers = []
for i in range(0,5):
    numbers += [int(input("what is the number"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save also variable names you can use python `dictionaries` like this:

```
number = {}
for i in range(0,5):
  number[f'number{i}'] = int(input("what is the number "))
print(number)
```

output:

```
{'number0': 5, 'number1': 4, 'number2': 5, 'number3': 6, 'number4': 3}
```